# phpinfo.php not returning info. Web Server Not Working. mac user

Tags: macos, php

```
<?php

echo phpinfo();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
?>
```

I am not getting any errors returned either.

phpinfo()  used to come up and provide all of that helpful info.

I had been successfully run `.php` scripts from Netbeans.

I had been successfully been connecting to MySQL database.

Everything stopped working when I started to run `.php` scripts in Dreamweaver.

I constantly get the error

```
Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.
```

I do not know why this would suddenly become a problem.

Note: I installed MAMP manually and as I said it everything was working just fine.

Someone suggested that there may be a conflict with my ports.

On the mac I just entered my IP address and scanned for ports.
 Here are the only two that seem relevant.
 port 80 = html
 port 8080 = html-alt

Someone suggested the following.

I checked my php.ini and short_open_tag is set to '1' as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: You don't need `echo` with `phpinfo();`

Comment: Regardless, your issue has nothing to do with your use of phpinfo(), but rather the fact that your webserver is either not running or not where you think it is. (different port?)

Comment: I was a little burned out from trying to resolve this for more than a couple of days and many hours straight each day. I named the file phpInfo.php. My WebServer is No longer working. It was working fine when I was launching from Netbeans and/or typing at the URL localhost/php folder/filename.php. Then I started to used Dreamweaver and from that point on I was no longer able to connect to my web server from Dreamweaver or from Netbeans. Some clear instructions on how to get reenable or troubleshoot my WebServer would be very much appreciated.i normally do not give up.this feels hopeless.

Comment: How are you _starting_ your webserver? Any error messages in its logfiles?

Comment: Can you refresh me on how to view the log files ?  I go in through terminal.  Thanks.